# Network Service User's Directory in IIS 6

Tags: iis, asp.net

I created an application pool and set its application pool identity to "Network Service" in IIS of Windows 2003. The problem is, when I set the identity to a user I can add some files to the user's directory and use them via IIS, but for "Network Service" account I cannot find the directory related to this user. 
I tried ASPNET user but no luck, any help would be appreciated.

cas

Comment: what is your goal? what do you mean with "user's directory"?

Comment: I mean the user profiles such as the directories in Documents and Settings directory.

Answer (score 2):

The network service, ASPNET user, etc do not have user profiles. They are just system accounts - basically a username, password and a little bit of metadata - not a full-fledged user that can log in to the machine terminal and have a MyDocuments folder, etc.

Comment: Alright I used "All Users" directory for this purpose, since the directory that I am going to put is not a private one, any user may access it no problem. Thanks for answering back w/ an informative reply.

Comment: @Cas sounds like a good solution. Cheers